# How i can display data column wise in loop

Tags: visualforce

How i can display data column wise insise loop. 
My code is.

```
 <div align="center">
  <apex:repeat value="{!data}" var="data1">                      
    <apex:pageBlock >
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!data1.Attachments}" var="a">
       <apex:column >
  <apex:image url="{!$Resource.pdfimg}" width="100"height="100"style="margin:20px;"/> 
        </apex:column>                  
   </apex:pageBlockTable>            
  </apex:pageBlock>
  </apex:repeat>
  </div>
```

This code is displaying images as:

```
 image1
 image2
 image3
```

I want to display as-

```
image1 image2 image3
```

How i can achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `apex:repeat` instead of `pageBlockTable` and put your images to the html table:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!data}" var="data1">
    <table border="0">
    <tr>
    <apex:repeat value="{!data1.Attachments}" var="a">  
        <td>
        <apex:image url="{!$Resource.pdfimg}" width="100"height="100"style="margin:20px;"/> 
        </td>
    </apex:repeat>
    </tr>
    </table>
</apex:repeat>
```

Comment: The table tags should be outside the repeat tags for proper display of multi-dimensional arrays. Otherwise you will get lots of tables, instead of just one.